# How to register commands in bundle only on dev environment

Tags: php, symfony, configuration, command-line-interface

So I have symfony 4.4 application and I would like to add new bundle that would be used only in dev environment to help with testing some backend functionalities. I would like this bundle to have commands that could be run on this dev enviroment only. On production enviroment such commands should be either not registered either disabled. Depends on implementation but overall goal here is to not be able to run such commands on production.

I know that such thing could be implemented by adding such check to command. But thing is that I would like not to have to add every time such lines. It should be done somehow automatically in other place. So when I would add 5 commands those 5 commands in bundle would be able to run only on dev environment

How can I achieve those 2 goals?

Comment: You could move the whole bundle out from the project and install it as a Composer dependency. You can add such dependency into `require-dev` section, which will result in the bundle not being installed on the production environment at all.

Comment: Just follow the examples in config/bundles.php.  Something like: `Prefix\MyBundle\MyBundle::class => ['dev' => true],